# jQuery. Выход из click функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть некоторое условие и click функция. И я не понимаю, почему, после того как он зашел в это условие и в функцию, он уже оттуда не выходит. 
По идее jQuery код выполнятся после каждого действия на странице, а он как будто вообще не выходит из этой функции.
Пыталась писать return, break - не помогает.

Вот [пример простого кода](http://jsfiddle.net/nd3mLx5r/2/), где я не понимаю, почему он так работает.

```
if (parseInt($('#number').text()) > 0) {
   $('#throw').click(function() {
     var a = parseInt($('#number').text());
     a -= 1;
     $('#number').text(a);
     alert(1);
     if (parseInt($('#number').text()) > 0) {
         return false;
     }
   });
} else {
    alert('end');
}
```

Comment: Этот код назначает элементу #throw обработчик события - не более того.
Где выполняется этот код? Что находится внутри функции-обработчика?

Comment: в скрипте html файла
там много что находится, добавила

Comment: Остаётся непонятным, где выполняется приведенный в вопросе код.
"Зашёл в условие и в функцию" - звучит странно, ведь когда "зашёл в условие" - "заходить в функцию" никто не будет, функция всего лишь назначается в качестве обработчика и сработает только при клике на #throw (если обработчик не будет впоследствии удалён/переопределён).

Comment: Не понимаю, что значит "где выполняется".

Comment: Функция, которую Вы назначаете в качестве обработчика события, будет выполнена, когда будет кликнут элемент "throw". Но в какой момент проверяется условие и назначается обработчик события? (Смущает то, что у Вас в вопросе поставлены рядом "зашёл в условие и в функцию" - когда "зашёл в условие", функция выполняться **не** будет, она будет вызвана только после клика).

Comment: Понятно, что функция будет вызвана только после клика. Проблема в том, что, когда проверяется условие, вызывается функция, выполняется ее содержимое, она не заканчивается, а начинается заново.

Comment: @Александра Мне тоже непонятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Могли бы вы   сделать минимальный пример проблемы? [Я сделал пример на jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd3mLx5r/1/), но не вижу в чём проблема.

Comment: Вот
http://jsfiddle.net/nd3mLx5r/2/

Comment: Спасибо, кажется понял проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вы хотите условие внутри функции, а не вне. Когда придется выкинуть функцию `click`, можно использовать `$('#throw').off('click');`.

Вот пример:

```js
$('#throw').click(function() {
  if (parseInt($('#number').text()) > 0) {
    var a = parseInt($('#number').text());
    a -= 1;
    $('#number').text(a);
    alert(1);
  } else {
    $('#throw').off('click');
    alert('end');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="number">5</span>
<button id="throw">throw</button>
```

Comment: Это помогло, но если мне потом еще нужна эта функция?

Comment: Если нужна, то без .off.click() можно

Comment: Я просто хочу, чтобы, когда значение станет равным нулю, он сразу пошел в else, а не ждал клика. Но тем не менее, эта функция мне еще потом нужна.

Comment: @Александра Функция уже не ждет клика. Этот код только назначает элементу #throw обработчик события click, а потом остальной код выполняется как обычно, ничего не ждет. Эта функция просто вызывается при каждого click'а.

Comment: Всё, я разобралась. Огромное спасибо!